# Array search to get key value doesn't work after json_decode

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have this JSON code:

```
[
{"id":16385,"value":"2"},
{"id":4121,"value":"Spiderman"},
{"id":78036,"value":"Batman"},
{"id":8075,"value":["I accept the terms"]}
]
```

I am having this `array` below out of using `json_decode`:

```
Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 16385 [value] => 2 ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 4121 [value] => Spiderman ) 
[2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 78036 [value] => Batman ) 
[3] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 8075 [value] => Array ( [0] => I accept the terms ) ) 
)
```

I want to use the `array_search`
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

So I wrote this:

```
$key = array_search('4121', $array);
```

I expected `$key` to be `1` but it is empty if I do `echo $key;`

Below my complete code:

```
function personen_tonen() { 
    ob_start();
    global $wpdb;

    //SQL query
    $sql = "SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(custom_fields, '$') AS 'Test' FROM `wp_bookly_customer_appointments`";

    $personen = $wpdb->get_results($sql);   

    foreach($personen as $persoon) {

        $array = $persoon->Test;
        $data = json_decode($array);

        print_r($data);

       $key = array_search('4121', $data);
       echo $key;

    }

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('personen', 'personen_tonen');
```

Comment: post the entire script (not the entire, but at least the lines where you create $array)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you *... want to use the `array_search()` function*, you need to use `json_decode()` with `true` as second parameter to decode the JSON string and convert the JSON content into associative arrays:

```
<?php
$json = '[
   {"id":16385,"value":"2"},
   {"id":4121,"value":"Spiderman"},
   {"id":78036,"value":"Batman"},
   {"id":8075,"value":["I accept the terms"]}
]';

$array = json_decode($json, true);
$key = array_search('4121', array_column($array, 'id'));
$value = array_column($array, 'value');
var_dump($key);
var_dump(array_column($array, 'value')[$key]);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks!, how can I `echo` the value of that `array key` after it?, so in this case `Spiderman`

Comment: Hi Berto: If I use `echo $array[$key]->value` nothing happens.

Comment: About the downvote - what's wrong with the answer (if the OP wants to use `array_search`)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `array_column` to get all the ids otherwise `array_search` will try to find the object `"4121"`, which is not what you want. Otherwise you can write your own algorithm:

```
$item = null;
foreach($array as $obj) {
    if ($obj->id == '4121') {
        $item = $obj;
        break;
    }
}
```

If efficiency is not a concern for you and you won't work with large set of data, use php's algorithm, otherwise consider using this (using array_column you have a O(2*n) complexity, with this solution O(n), so it will be up to 2 times faster)